# PHP - How to convert a Array from (Key, Value) to (Key, Value, Value)?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a table in a HTML file, using my CODE below I have managed to get all values from this table as a Array.

The problem is my CODE makes Array as: **(Key -> Value) (Key -> Value)**. But the structure of my data is: **(Key -> Value, Value) (Key -> Value, Value)**

Here is Content of: `myHTMLfile.html`

```
<td height="22" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">1 Hour </td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">400 USD</td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">450 USD</td>
<td height="22" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">2 Hours</td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">500 USD</td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">600 USD</td>
<td height="22" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">3 Hours </td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">600 USD</td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">700 USD</td>
```

Im using this CODE to get content and make this Array:

```
$file = ("myHTMLfile.html");
$searchfor = 'align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"';                     

header('Content-Type: text/html');   
$html = file_get_contents($file);

$pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');
$pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m";
if(preg_match_all($pattern, $html, $matches)); 

function remap_alternating(array $values) {
    $remapped = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < count($values) - 1; $i += 2) {

$remapped[strip_tags(trim($values[$i]))] = strip_tags(trim($values[$i + 1]));
    }
    return $remapped;
}
$mapped = remap_alternating($matches[0]);
// RAM 
$keys = array_map("trim", array_map("strip_tags", array_keys($mapped)));
$values = array_map("trim", array_map("strip_tags", array_values($mapped)));
$mapped = array_combine($keys, $values);
```

Below you can see the results I get from `var_dump($mapped);`

```
array(4) {
  ["1 Hour"]=>
  string(7) "400 USD"
  ["450 USD"]=>
  string(7) "2 Hours"
  ["500 USD"]=>
  string(7) "600 USD"
  ["3 Hours"]=>
  string(7) "600 USD"
}
```

I want this Array results to look like:

```
array(3) {
  ["1 Hour"]=>
  string(16) "400 USD, 450 USD"
  ["2 Hours"]=>
  string(16) "500 USD, 600 USD"
  ["3 Hours"]=>
  string(7) "600 USD"
}
```

**My question is**: What is the correct PHP programming CODE to get the results as I want?

**UPDATED BELOW**

I found a example and it looks like its what I need. But how can I use it with my CODE above?

**Example:**

```
$get = "first=value1&second=value2&third=value3";

print_r(array_map2("explode","=",explode("&",$get)));
```

**would print out:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => first
            [1] => value1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => second
            [1] => value2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => third
            [1] => value3
        )
)
```

Comment: A correct PHP code is a working one

Comment: @RoyalBg: Awesome.. What does it LOOK like? ;-)

Comment: It looks like any other PHP code, variables, functions, etc.. inside of `<?php` tags. Now, seriously, you shown no effort of solving your problem. Give us beside the info how did you get the array, how did you try to change it. And we may help you

Comment: @RoyalBg: I may not be so good as you, but I spent almost 1 week to create the simple code which I show you on how I get this Array. That took me MANY hours many days and 2 other people helped me to get that far. Its rude to say that I don't try.. Anyway, now Im stuck at this point shown above. And have no idea how to continue. Any hint/tips would help. Thanks.

Comment: It will be much easier to help if You post myHTMLfile.html

Comment: @Gustek: I have updated my question and added `myHTMLfile.html`

Comment: @Cyborg do you want to rearange to current array or to change your current functions to extract the array different way? If you want to rearange, you can add the keys and values to acomma separated string, then explode it, and by looping +2 to add to new array smth like `$newArr[$arr[$i]] = $arr[$i+1].','.$arr[$i+2];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
function remap_alternating(array $values) {
    $remapped = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < count($values) - 1; $i += 3) {
    $remapped[strip_tags(trim($values[$i]))] = array(strip_tags(trim($values[$i + 1])), strip_tags(trim($values[$i + 2])));
    }
    return $remapped;
}
```

Comment: Your CODE is almost correct, but it makes 1 problem. I get ERROR on LINE 34. LINE 34: `$values = array_map("trim", array_map("strip_tags", array_values($mapped)));`. I need this line or some other function to TRIM whitespace. Using your CODE every thing looks good except this contain whitespace: `["1 Hour "]=>` but `["2 Hours"]=>` looks good.. How to solve this? Thank you

Comment: you should switch the trim and striptags:

Comment: $remapped[trim(strip_tags($values[$i]))] = array(trim(strip_tags($values[$i + 1])), trim(strip_tags($values[$i + 2])));

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do but I think you are searching for the map function
http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-map.php